# How to add variables into graph margins using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, cowplot

I'd like to add variable information (for instance "Case" from the data) in the margin (horitzontal or vertical) that changes with each year - preferably more than one variable actually - similar concept to what ggMarginal would produce but the output to be numerical view of what was in the data instead of a graphical representation.

the picture is of one graph within a larger facet. i used dput() on the data which is listed below the code.  side question - is the result of the dput() an object? a dataframe?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# see below for dput representation of dataframe named ultimates

lim_inc <- ultimates[,c("Policy.Period.Inception","Limited.Incurred")]

format_bignum = function(n){
  case_when(
    n >= 1e12 ~ paste(round(n/1e12,2), 'Tn'),
    n >= 1e9 ~ paste(round(n/1e9,2), 'Bn'),
    n >= 1e5 ~ paste(round(n/1e6,2), 'M'),
    n >= 1e3 ~ paste(round(n/1e3), 'K'),
    TRUE ~ as.character(n))
}

# plot
ggplot(ultimates) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=method,xend=method,y=Selected,yend=loss),
               color="black") +
  geom_point(aes(x=method,y=loss),color=rgb(0.1,0,0.8,0.5),size=3) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=Selected),color="red") +        
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=Exp.Chg),linetype = 2, color="red", alpha = 1) +
  geom_hline(data=lim_inc,aes(yintercept=Limited.Incurred))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf,xmax=Inf,ymin=Prior,ymax=Selected, fill = Pos.Neg),alpha=.02)+
  scale_fill_manual("Pos.Neg", values = c("green", "red"))+
    # geom_text(data=ultimates,mapping=aes(x = Inf, y= Inf, label = IBNR))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = format_bignum)+
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  xlab("Development Methods") +
  ylab("Loss Estimates") +
  facet_wrap(vars(Policy.Period.Inception),scales = "free")
```

data:

```
ultimates <- structure(list(Policy.Period.Inception = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", 
"2002-01-01", "2006-09-05", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", 
"2017-12-31", "Total"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Selected = c(2132231.31, 
1665596.9, 3511790.82, 3861764.3625, 3306045.105, 2102924.43, 
3396019.1525, 2870100.145, 22846472.225, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 
3511790.82, 3861764.3625, 3306045.105, 2102924.43, 3396019.1525, 
2870100.145, 22846472.225, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3511790.82, 
3861764.3625, 3306045.105, 2102924.43, 3396019.1525, 2870100.145, 
22846472.225, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3511790.82, 3861764.3625, 
3306045.105, 2102924.43, 3396019.1525, 2870100.145, 22846472.225, 
2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3511790.82, 3861764.3625, 3306045.105, 
2102924.43, 3396019.1525, 2870100.145, 22846472.225, 2132231.31, 
1665596.9, 3511790.82, 3861764.3625, 3306045.105, 2102924.43, 
3396019.1525, 2870100.145, 22846472.225, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 
3511790.82, 3861764.3625, 3306045.105, 2102924.43, 3396019.1525, 
2870100.145, 22846472.225, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3511790.82, 
3861764.3625, 3306045.105, 2102924.43, 3396019.1525, 2870100.145, 
22846472.225), Prior = c(2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3526773.92, 3904052.96, 
3217426.775, 2146089.31, 3525503.535, 3147669.775, 23265344.485, 
2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3526773.92, 3904052.96, 3217426.775, 2146089.31, 
3525503.535, 3147669.775, 23265344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 
3526773.92, 3904052.96, 3217426.775, 2146089.31, 3525503.535, 
3147669.775, 23265344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3526773.92, 
3904052.96, 3217426.775, 2146089.31, 3525503.535, 3147669.775, 
23265344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3526773.92, 3904052.96, 
3217426.775, 2146089.31, 3525503.535, 3147669.775, 23265344.485, 
2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3526773.92, 3904052.96, 3217426.775, 2146089.31, 
3525503.535, 3147669.775, 23265344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 
3526773.92, 3904052.96, 3217426.775, 2146089.31, 3525503.535, 
3147669.775, 23265344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3526773.92, 
3904052.96, 3217426.775, 2146089.31, 3525503.535, 3147669.775, 
23265344.485), Limited.Incurred = c(2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3505158.47, 
3740667.09, 2823069.04, 1547379.24, 2552219.61, 1127388.42, 19093710.08, 
2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3505158.47, 3740667.09, 2823069.04, 1547379.24, 
2552219.61, 1127388.42, 19093710.08, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3505158.47, 
3740667.09, 2823069.04, 1547379.24, 2552219.61, 1127388.42, 19093710.08, 
2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3505158.47, 3740667.09, 2823069.04, 1547379.24, 
2552219.61, 1127388.42, 19093710.08, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3505158.47, 
3740667.09, 2823069.04, 1547379.24, 2552219.61, 1127388.42, 19093710.08, 
2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3505158.47, 3740667.09, 2823069.04, 1547379.24, 
2552219.61, 1127388.42, 19093710.08, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3505158.47, 
3740667.09, 2823069.04, 1547379.24, 2552219.61, 1127388.42, 19093710.08, 
2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3505158.47, 3740667.09, 2823069.04, 1547379.24, 
2552219.61, 1127388.42, 19093710.08), Ult.Change = c(0, 0, -14983.1000000001, 
-42288.5975000001, 88618.3300000001, -43164.8800000004, -129484.3825, 
-277569.63, -418872.260000001, 0, 0, -14983.1000000001, -42288.5975000001, 
88618.3300000001, -43164.8800000004, -129484.3825, -277569.63, 
-418872.260000001, 0, 0, -14983.1000000001, -42288.5975000001, 
88618.3300000001, -43164.8800000004, -129484.3825, -277569.63, 
-418872.260000001, 0, 0, -14983.1000000001, -42288.5975000001, 
88618.3300000001, -43164.8800000004, -129484.3825, -277569.63, 
-418872.260000001, 0, 0, -14983.1000000001, -42288.5975000001, 
88618.3300000001, -43164.8800000004, -129484.3825, -277569.63, 
-418872.260000001, 0, 0, -14983.1000000001, -42288.5975000001, 
88618.3300000001, -43164.8800000004, -129484.3825, -277569.63, 
-418872.260000001, 0, 0, -14983.1000000001, -42288.5975000001, 
88618.3300000001, -43164.8800000004, -129484.3825, -277569.63, 
-418872.260000001, 0, 0, -14983.1000000001, -42288.5975000001, 
88618.3300000001, -43164.8800000004, -129484.3825, -277569.63, 
-418872.260000001), A.v.E = c(0, 0, -20000, -60000, 120000, -30000, 
-135000, -350000, -475000, 0, 0, -20000, -60000, 120000, -30000, 
-135000, -350000, -475000, 0, 0, -20000, -60000, 120000, -30000, 
-135000, -350000, -475000, 0, 0, -20000, -60000, 120000, -30000, 
-135000, -350000, -475000, 0, 0, -20000, -60000, 120000, -30000, 
-135000, -350000, -475000, 0, 0, -20000, -60000, 120000, -30000, 
-135000, -350000, -475000, 0, 0, -20000, -60000, 120000, -30000, 
-135000, -350000, -475000, 0, 0, -20000, -60000, 120000, -30000, 
-135000, -350000, -475000), Exp.Chg = c(2132231.31, 1665596.9, 
3506773.92, 3844052.96, 3337426.775, 2116089.31, 3390503.535, 
2797669.775, 22790344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3506773.92, 
3844052.96, 3337426.775, 2116089.31, 3390503.535, 2797669.775, 
22790344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3506773.92, 3844052.96, 
3337426.775, 2116089.31, 3390503.535, 2797669.775, 22790344.485, 
2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3506773.92, 3844052.96, 3337426.775, 2116089.31, 
3390503.535, 2797669.775, 22790344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 
3506773.92, 3844052.96, 3337426.775, 2116089.31, 3390503.535, 
2797669.775, 22790344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3506773.92, 
3844052.96, 3337426.775, 2116089.31, 3390503.535, 2797669.775, 
22790344.485, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3506773.92, 3844052.96, 
3337426.775, 2116089.31, 3390503.535, 2797669.775, 22790344.485, 
2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3506773.92, 3844052.96, 3337426.775, 2116089.31, 
3390503.535, 2797669.775, 22790344.485), Pos.Neg = c(NA, NA, 
"Neg", "Neg", "Pos", "Neg", "Neg", "Neg", NA, NA, NA, "Neg", 
"Neg", "Pos", "Neg", "Neg", "Neg", NA, NA, NA, "Neg", "Neg", 
"Pos", "Neg", "Neg", "Neg", NA, NA, NA, "Neg", "Neg", "Pos", 
"Neg", "Neg", "Neg", NA, NA, NA, "Neg", "Neg", "Pos", "Neg", 
"Neg", "Neg", NA, NA, NA, "Neg", "Neg", "Pos", "Neg", "Neg", 
"Neg", NA, NA, NA, "Neg", "Neg", "Pos", "Neg", "Neg", "Neg", 
NA, NA, NA, "Neg", "Neg", "Pos", "Neg", "Neg", "Neg", NA), IBNR = c(0, 
0, 6632.34999999963, 121097.2725, 482976.065, 555545.19, 843799.5425, 
1742711.725, NA, 0, 0, 6632.34999999963, 121097.2725, 482976.065, 
555545.19, 843799.5425, 1742711.725, NA, 0, 0, 6632.34999999963, 
121097.2725, 482976.065, 555545.19, 843799.5425, 1742711.725, 
NA, 0, 0, 6632.34999999963, 121097.2725, 482976.065, 555545.19, 
843799.5425, 1742711.725, NA, 0, 0, 6632.34999999963, 121097.2725, 
482976.065, 555545.19, 843799.5425, 1742711.725, NA, 0, 0, 6632.34999999963, 
121097.2725, 482976.065, 555545.19, 843799.5425, 1742711.725, 
NA, 0, 0, 6632.34999999963, 121097.2725, 482976.065, 555545.19, 
843799.5425, 1742711.725, NA, 0, 0, 6632.34999999963, 121097.2725, 
482976.065, 555545.19, 843799.5425, 1742711.725, NA), Case = c(0, 
0, 5000, 80000, 5e+05, 3e+05, 1200000, 3e+05, NA, 0, 0, 5000, 
80000, 5e+05, 3e+05, 1200000, 3e+05, NA, 0, 0, 5000, 80000, 5e+05, 
3e+05, 1200000, 3e+05, NA, 0, 0, 5000, 80000, 5e+05, 3e+05, 1200000, 
3e+05, NA, 0, 0, 5000, 80000, 5e+05, 3e+05, 1200000, 3e+05, NA, 
0, 0, 5000, 80000, 5e+05, 3e+05, 1200000, 3e+05, NA, 0, 0, 5000, 
80000, 5e+05, 3e+05, 1200000, 3e+05, NA, 0, 0, 5000, 80000, 5e+05, 
3e+05, 1200000, 3e+05, NA), method = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Chain.Ladder.Pd", "Chain.Ladder.Inc", 
"Chain.Ladder.OS", "BF.Pd", "BF.Inc", "CC.Pd", "CC.Inc", "FreqSev"
), class = "factor"), loss = c(2152784.02, 1684495.67, 3547981.72, 
3822401.93, 3169561.23, 1821927.12, 3383436.67, 1751258.22, 21333846.58, 
2213044.47, 1741149.71, 3659701.4, 3924259.05, 3395126.52, 1724397.15, 
3660876.94, 1612489.86, 21931045.1, 2132231.31, 1665596.9, 3511790.82, 
3789963.01, 3070560.12, 1863564.29, 3225840.12, 1823992.82, 21083539.39, 
2172824, 1708855.78, 3562158.71, 3829743.28, 3205255.42, 2019568.66, 
3380766.3, 2694147.73, 22573319.88, 2287495.48, 1832908.54, 3710247.88, 
3944290.14, 3424091.65, 2248956.1, 3524386.34, 3330426.48, 24302802.61, 
2157008.55, 1692534.85, 3542170.84, 3806836.99, 3181864.54, 1969797.62, 
3284617.91, 2466502.39, 22101333.69, 2230039.34, 1773207.61, 
3636442.43, 3866187.04, 2500000, 2173375.34, 3394306.06, 2989323.98, 
22562881.8, 2152784, 1683653.83, 3546208.57, 3818583.3, 3170373.93, 
1832612.66, 3380298.79, 1823691.87, 21408206.95)), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what your desired result looks like; perhaps you can add further details to the picture you uploaded? I've removed the data preprocessing code, since you've also provided the final result in dput form. As for your side question, the result of `dput` is a ASCII text representation of whatever object you passed to the function, so when you use it on a data frame, the result will be a data frame.